# Error handling while loading the data in Oracle Apex 22.1.4

Tags: oracle, error-handling, oracle-apex, apex, error-log

I am using Oracle Apex 22.1.4 version. My requirement is to capture the error records and store them somewhere else while loading the data from xlsx/csv file.

If it's stored in some error log tables/ somewhere else internally, I can create a report on top of that table and display them to the users.

I saw one of the blogs from Oracle and I came to know that it was a very simple and easy method of capturing error records and storing them in Error tables in Oracle Apex 19.1

https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/quick-and-easy-data-loading-with-apex-191

Is there any similar way of capturing error data and storing them in Oracle Apex 22.1?

If yes, please give me suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That blog is about Apex version 19.1. You're on 22.1. So... that functionality should be available in your version too. Did you try ? What were your findings ?

Comment: I have implemented Log into Error Log method for Error Handling in 22.1 based on the article from Oracle.

The error table contains the details of the error records. One of the errors is ORA-01843: not a valid month.

There are 7 date columns in the target table. I want to know for which date column, the error is present in it.

Is there any way to find that?

Comment: Want to provide some sample data I could take a look

Comment: I have some date values like 12/17/2021, 01/12/2022, 01/12/2022, 01/12/2022, 01/12/2022, 31/07/2025, 01/12/2021 in seven fields.

The date format should be DD/MM/YYYY in my case. So the first field will not follow the rules since its value is 12/17/2021. (Month ranges from 01 to 12 and not 17)

In the error handling, I am getting the error as ORA-01843: not a valid month. But I need to know, out of 7 fields which field doesn't follow the rules? (Which field has incorrect date format).

Is there any way to find that in the error handling itself?

Comment: Don't think there is in this way of loading. It is a plain insert statement that is failing and you get the error as is. A workaround would be to load everything unvalidated in your own table, all in varchar2(4000) columns and then writing your own routine to verify the data and move it to the actual table (with errors in an error table). That way you can control the error messages in a more granular way

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I will try that method for doing the validation and storing the error messages.